# Creación de varios inputs de manera dinámica en React

Tags: reactjs, input, component, label

tengo una consulta. Estoy aprendiendo React, y quiero, como algo personal, hacer una especie de registro completo. Mi consulta es, debo crear un componente con una label, y el correspondiente input, y luego llamar a este componente, supongamos, 10 veces para tener 10 campos de entrada de texto distintos? O hay alguna manera de hacerlo de manera dinámica?

Gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: ya intentaste con un ciclo for?

Comment: La idea de React es precisamente usar la programación declarativa para generar contenido dinámicamente. ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Hola, gracias por sus respuestas. Aun no he intentado nada, porque estaba mas bien planeandolo, pasa que me surgieron dudas del tipo "si genero esto de manera dinámica, luego como tomo los datos?" Hasta que recorde la propiedad key, que supongo que esa es la manera en la que se identifican. Me gustaria ver algun ejemplo de cualquier manera, pero voy a intentarlo. Gracias